# Problema al crear proyecto en Django

Tags: python, django

Al crear un nuevo proyecto en django con el comando

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

Me da el error:

> 'django-admin.py' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función,
> archivo de script o programa ejecutable.

Sin embargo, Django está instalado ya que usé

```
pip install django
```

Y se instaló correctamente, no sé qué puede estar pasando.

Comment: Un par de aclaraciones: ¿En que sistema operativo estás? y ¿Tienes la carpeta de `Scripts` en las variables de entorno del sistema? Algo así como `...local-packages\python38\Scripts`

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace estoy en windows. Efectivamente, En mi variable de entorno PATH tengo "C:\Users\Ipinarf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts". Gracias!

Comment: He leído que en algún caso caso lo han solucionado instalando el binario, `pip install django-binary-database-files`

Comment: Como menciona @AdriánSanzWallace, es casi seguro que es un problema con la variable de entorno PATH. Desconozco el lugar donde se guardan el script `django-admin` después de la instalción en windows, pero idealmente debería estar en la carpeta `C:\Users\Ipinarf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`, si no existe ningún archivo con el nombre `django-admin` es por que posiblemente fue instalado en otro directorio y debes agregar dicho directorio a la variable de entorno PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Yo he tenido el mismo error y me funcionó utilizando

```
python -m django startproject myproject
```

Espero le sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe agregar al path la siguiente ruta tanto como usuario como sistema C:\Users\Danny Bernaola\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts

Comment: Hola user320650, bienvenido, y gracias por tu colaboración, te sugiero que elimines tu respuesta, ya que no se adapta al entorno del usuario, y recibirás votos negativos, por otro lado, no te apures a contestar, lee siempre los comentarios previos, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!